# Random Avro data generator in Java/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro

Is this possible to generate random Avro data by the specified schema using `org.apache.avro` library?
I need to produce this data with Kafka.

I tried to find some kind of random data generator for test, however, I have stumbled upon tools for such data generator or GenericRecord usage. Tools are not very suitable for me as there is a specific file dependency (like reading the file and so on) and GenericRecord should be generated one-by-one as I've understood.

Are there any other solutions for Java/Scala?

UPDATE: I have found [this class](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/avro/trunk/lang/java/avro/src/test/java/org/apache/avro/RandomData.java) but it does not seem to beaccessible from org.apache.avro version version 1.8.2

Answer (score 2):

The reason you need to read a file, is that it matches a Schema, which defines the fields that need to be created, and of which types.

That is not a hard requirement, and there would be nothing preventing creation of random `Generic` or `Specific` Records that are built in code via Avro's `SchemaBuilder` class

See [this repo for example](https://github.com/gwenshap/kafka-examples/blob/master/AvroProducerExample/src/main/java/com/shapira/examples/producer/avroclicks/EventGenerator.java), that uses a POJO generated from an AVSC schema (which again, could be done with `SchemaBuilder` instead) into a Java class.

Even the class you linked to [uses a schema file](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/util/RandomData.java#L149)

Answer (score 1):

So I personally would probably use Avro4s (https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s) in conjunction with scalachecks (https://www.scalacheck.org) `Gen` to model such tests.

You could use scalacheck to generate random instances of case classes and avro4s to convert them to generic records, extract their schema etc etc.

There's also avro-mocker https://github.com/speedment/avro-mocker though I don't know how easy it is to hook into the code.

Comment: It seems like it is still needed to create specific records one-by-one with Avro4s. Am I right? As I need to have at least 100 records in a batch for testing and creating them manually is tedious

Comment: that's where scalachecks `Gen` comes in. with it you can create an arbitrary amount of instances of a given case class which you then can transform to `GenericRecord` using Avro4s

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use Podam http://mtedone.github.io/podam/ to generate POJOs and then just output them to Avro using Java Avro library https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedjava.html#Serializing

Comment: Could you give an example of how to convert them to Avro?

Comment: Use standard lib that vmcan write to a file. https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedjava.html#Serializing

Comment: *SpecificDatumWriter class is used with **generated classes** and extracts the schema from the specified generated type* -- That doesn't work for any POJO